# Json String can't decode when end of string have `\'

Tags: javascript, json, decode, extjs4.2

When JSON string has `\` at the end of any string it gives me:

> Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String

JSON decode error:

> Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON
>   String:
>
> ```
> [{"ID1":"1","ID2":"1","NAME":"Act\"},{"ID1":"3","ID2":"1","NAME":"Act\"},{"ID1":"4","ID2":"2","NAME":"act $#%^&amp;&amp;*"},{"ID1":"2","ID2":"2","NAME":"act $#%^&amp;&amp;*"}]
> ```

How can i avoid above error?

Comment: Your JSON indeed is invalid, so just fix it

Comment: Where is your JSON coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is invalid JSON, because the `\` character escapes the `"` mark which would be responsible for closing the string - as such, your string remains unclosed (that is, until the next `"` comes around).

So your problem is that a backslash has a special meaning inside strings. If you want to use slashes, use `\\` instead. (Note that what this does is escape the backslash character itself.)

ie.:

```
{"ID1":"1","ID2":"1","NAME":"Act\\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape that backslash. Initially I thought you would only need to use one escape character, but, [according to this demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/u57t5tLn/), you need to use three:

```
{"ID1":"1","ID2":"1","NAME":"Act\\\\"}
```

Comment: This is misleading. JSON requires ``\\`` to encode a backslash. Javascript requires ``\\`` to encode a backslash in a string literal. Therefore, to represent a ``\`` in json data within a javascript string literal, you need ``\\\\``.

Comment: However, you should never need to put JSON within a js string literal

Answer (score 0):

If you test your JSON, you will see that it's not valid : http://jsonlint.com/
You'll need to escape your \ with another  \

```
\\Act
```

You should encode your JSON before, or make it manually if possible.